# Possible exceptions from drive api calls

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm building an Android app that uses drive as its backup solution.  It needs to work offline.  Obviously not the actual "backup" part of it.  We queue files to be pushed/pulled until favorable network connections exist.

To do this properly, we need to be very precise about the exceptions that come out of the code called.  I can't find a really solid list of possible exceptions from the Drive API calls.  I need to know, basically, if an exception that comes out of the api is networking/temporary in nature, or something that's permanent (permissions issue, etc).

AFAIK, code isn't open source, which I was a little surprised by.  The api is public, and I can't imagine that the code is overly sensitive.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The code for the Drive client library is certainly open source. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs) is a list of all API client libraries Java supports. Go to Drive and click "Download the latest version of the library". In the downloaded zip will be the jars you need to depend on as well as source jars that contain the full source code.

Comment: Weird.  Missed that.  You are correct.  Will start nerding out and see what I find.  May answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

`IOException` and `GoogleAuthException` should cover all cases.

Comment: Well, it doesn't.  Not really.  Does IOException mean its a network issue, or the file wasn't found?  I had some other exception about permissions.  That kind of thing.  Network issues will resolve.  The rest won't.